# WhatsApp service extended to lifetime and revoked immediately?

Tags: whatsapp-messenger

I just saw the following when I opened Whatsapp:

[image: lifetime service]

Within few minutes I get the following message:

[image: revoked service]

Why is this happening?

Comment: Happened to several other people as well. As of now, seems like the reason is unknown.

Answer (score 5):

It sounds like other blogs are talking about it:

- [WhatsApp is now free and promises to stay ad-free - Yahoo! News](http://news.yahoo.com/whatsapp-now-free-promises-stay-111137277.html)
- [WhatsApp, why you gotta be so rude? - techshout](http://www.techshout.com/software/2016/19/whatsapp-why-you-gotta-be-so-rude/)

[WhatsApp official blog](https://blog.whatsapp.com/615/Making-WhatsApp-free-and-more-useful) says that the app is going free:

> So over the next several weeks, we'll remove fees from the different versions of our app and WhatsApp will no longer charge you for our service.